# empty text box on text change causes by auto post back in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postback

i make an event on text changes and i set autoPostBack="true" but when text box changed , the text box became empty and i want to avoid refresh of page without set 
autoPostBack="false" .

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. You are using Web forms? Any kind of Ajax framework? It is not recommended to use the textchanged event in webforms directly (it will probably not work properly), because it will cause your form be sent to server in every text change (the textbox will send first letter, then clean, looking empty every time). If you want to handle text validations in the client, you can use javascript,or some kind of ajax approach.

Comment: no i am not use ajax  its web form with c# code behind

Comment: as @FelipeTorres suggested textchange is not the right way to do it. Use a blur event instead or use ajax + textchange event together to send the text to the server.

Comment: show your exact code please